# Sum multiple columns in 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables(sales_today and last_year_same_day_sales).  From sales_today table, I would like to sum both t_net_sales and t_gross_margin columns.
From last_year_same_day_sales, I would like to sum both ly_net_sales and ly_gross_margin columns and display results in one table as I have shown below

```
sales_today
store_number | t_net_sales | t_gross_margin
1            | 100.00      | 20.00
2            | 150.00      | 35.00

last_year_same_day_sales
store_number | ly_net_sales| ly_gross_margin
1            | 175.00      | 50.00
2            | 125.00      | 25.00
3            | 75.00       | 10.00

results
today_net_sales | last_year_net_sales | today_gross_margin | last_year_gross_margin
250.00          | 375.00              | 55.00              | 85.00
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(t_net_sales) FROM sales_today) AS today_net_sales,
  (SELECT SUM(ly_net_sales) FROM last_year_same_day_sales) AS last_year_net_sales,
  (SELECT SUM(t_gross_margin) FROM sales_today) AS today_gross_margin,
  (SELECT SUM(ly_gross_margin) FROM last_year_same_day_sales) AS last_year_gross_margin
```

I get the proper results with the query. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not getting it to work.  Could you give me a complete query on what you believe would be better?

Comment: The things people believe. Tsk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the subqueries to the `from` clause and use only two:

```
SELECT st.today_net_sales, st.today_gross_margin,
       ly.last_year_net_sales, ly.last_year_gross_margin
FROM (SELECT SUM(t_net_sales) as today_net_sales,
             SUM(t_gross_margin) as today_gross_margin
      FROM sales_today
     ) st CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(ly_net_sales) as last_year_net_sales,
             SUM(ly_gross_margin) as last_year_gross_margin
      FROM last_year_same_day_sales
     ) ly;
```

This should have better performance than your version, because the two tables are only scanned once each.